# Table extending beyond the page width

Tags: tables, margins, tabularx

I know there are a few posts with similar titles. But my case is different. When I use `\documentclass{article}`, my table fits properly on the page. But when I use my university's document class `\documentclass{ucr}`, my table becomes stretched and goes beyond the page width.

The code that works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[top=1in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}}
\toprule 
\centering{}Parameters & \centering{}GARCH-N & \centering{}GARCH-t\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
$\delta$ & \centering{}0.1106{*} (6.50)  & \centering{}.1084{*} (6.1425) \tabularnewline
$\beta_{1}$ & \centering{}0.630{*} (9.64)  & \centering{}0.629{*} (9.031) \tabularnewline
$\alpha_{0}$ & \centering{}0.008{*} (2.86)  & \centering{}0.008{*} (2.855) \tabularnewline
$\alpha_{1}$ & \centering{}0.203{*} (4.15)  & \centering{}0.232{*} (4.412) \tabularnewline
$\alpha_{2}$ & \centering{}0.663{*} (10.34)  & \centering{}0.639{*} (9.261) \tabularnewline
$\text{\ensuremath{\nu}}$ &  & \centering{}5.51{*} (63.53) \tabularnewline
Log- Likelihood & 14.603 & 26.318\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\begin{doublespace}
\caption{Blah blah}
%\end{doublespace}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The code that does not work is the same as the above except the first line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucr}
```

You can download the ucr class file called LaTex Template (Chairperson)* from http://graduate.ucr.edu/filingresources.html

I will be grateful if you could provide some suggestions here.

Comment: you are using `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}}` so assuming you have 6cm (+36pt cell padding) available. If a different class has a narrower text width than that then the table will not fit. You do not need p columns here anyway why not simply use `c` columns and let the table be its natural width

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I use `c` columns then the standard errors (numbers inside the parentheses) do not get placed under the coefficients, rather they are placed on the right side of each coefficient. How can I overcome this?

Comment: @TRa: You can use simple `c` type columns and keep the standard errors in the line underneath the coefficient of you insert your data  in two rows as follows: `$\delta$ & 0.1106  & .1084 \\
 & (6.50)  &  (6.1425) \\  `

Comment: @leandriis sure I can do that. I just wanted to avoid doing it since that means retyping all my tables now.

Comment: @TRa - Employing (abusing!, really) the `p` column type might appear to be convenient at first, but it precludes you from implementing truly decent typesetting practices such as aligning the numbers on their respective decimal markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, whatever else you do, delete (or comment out) the penultimate line in `ucr.cls`, viz., the instruction `\dsp`. It is simply unconscionable to impose triple-spacing. (That final `\dsp` directive comes on top of other commands that increase line-spacing as well! Yikes!!)

Second, you're definitely abusing the `p` column type. (The `ucr` document class does a separate "job" on the `p` column type...) It would be much better if you placed the standard errors on separate lines and used a basic `c` column type for columns 2 and 3. (And, use the `l` ("left") column type, not `c` or `p`, for the first column.) Even better, load the `dcolumn` package and align the numbers in columns 2 and 3 on their decimal markers; see the following code for an application.

Do get rid of all `\centering{}` directives, and please replace `$\text{\ensuremath{\nu}}$` with `$\nu$`. The less code clutter, the better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucr-mod}   % modified by commenting out the final `\dsp` directive
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l d{3.5} d{3.5} }
\toprule 
Parameters & \mc{GARCH-N} & \mc{GARCH-t}\\
\midrule 
$\delta$     & 0.1106^{*}   & 0.1084^{*}  \\
  & (6.50) & (6.1425) \\
$\beta_{1}$  & 0.630^{*}    & 0.629^{*}  \\
  & (9.64) & (9.031) \\
$\alpha_{0}$ & 0.008^{*}    & 0.008^{*}  \\
  & (2.86) & (2.855) \\
$\alpha_{1}$ & 0.203^{*}    & 0.232^{*}  \\
  & (4.15) & (4.412) \\
$\alpha_{2}$ & 0.663^{*}    & 0.639^{*}  \\
  & (10.34) & (9.261) \\
$\nu$        &             & 5.51^{*}   \\
  & & (63.53) \\
Log-Likelihood & 14.603 & 26.318\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Blah blah}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! In your code, did you manually place all those standard errors on separate lines? I was just hoping there would be an easier way to do this. But thank you very much again for your valuable time.

Comment: @TRa - I think it took me about 2 minutes to place the standard errors on separate lines. Entirely doable, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. By the way, it's an honor talking to you here, sir.

Comment: @TRa - I'm blushing...